# VB InStr Equivalent in c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am not sure why I get the result of `0`, which is the correct value of `a`

I have in VB

```
Dim searched As String = "<results>" & vbCrLf & "<field name=\""FID\""/>" & vbCrLf & "<field name=\""StartFID\""/>" & vbCrLf & "<field name=\""Vertex1\""/>" & vbCrLf & "<field name=\""Vertex2\""/>" & vbCrLf & "<field name=\""Slope\""/>" & vbCrLf & ""

Dim sought As String = "<rs FID=\""87\"" StartFID=\""87\"" Vertex1=\""29\"" Vertex2=\""30\"" Slope=\""-1\""/>"

Dim a As Integer = InStr(searched, sought)
```

What I would like to do, is get the same result of `a == 0` when converted to c#.

I have tried

```
int a = String.Compare(searched, sought);
int a = String.IndexOf(searched, sought);
int a = String.Equals(searched, sought);
```

Comment: what's wrong with `searched.IndexOf(sought)`?

Comment: Carsten's right, `IndexOf` should do the same thing, more or less.

Comment: Try Strings.InStr(). Link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47d6yh63(v=vs.110).aspx. Add  Microsoft.VisualBasic dll in reference. else IndexOf is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks Carsten.  I thought I tried that.. Apparently not.. Works  Thanks again.

Comment: What's with the `\"` in your VB strings?  Escape sequences like that are not valid in VB.  Your strings may not contain what you think they contain.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  I'm checking into the contents of the strings

Comment: Used on C# as Schedule.Options_Attributes.ToUpper().IndexOf("BAY DEPARTMENT") and worked fine !

Answer (score 5):

Strings in C# are zero-indexed. If `a.IndexOf(b)` returns `0`, then string `b` is present in string `a` at position `0`.

If the sought string is not in the input, `IndexOf()` returns `-1`.

Answer (score 4):

One difference between `InStr` and `IndexOf`'s behavior is that `InStr` returns zero when the string is not found, while `IndexOf` returns -1. Using `IndexOf` is the idiomatic way of searching for substrings in C#, and the correct method to use in your situation.

If you would like to use `InStr` directly, you could do it by referencing `Microsoft.VisualBasic` assembly, and then calling `InStr` as a static method of the `Strings` class:

```
int a = Strings.InStr(searched, sought);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response  I was thinking as well that InStr and IndexOf both returned 0 if found   wich is not correct on my part

Comment: @Deke The only reason I could think of using `InStr` from a C# code is to emulate specific output from VB.NET. In particular, it would be incorrect to use the returned value as an index into the original string.

Comment: I dont want to use InStr in C#. I want to use IndexOf

Answer (score 4):

Simply You can use IndexOf()+1 to return 0 instead of -1

```
int a = searched.IndexOf(sought)+1;
```

it work for me hop it help

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `searched.Contains(sought)`

Answer (score 0):

`String.IndexOf` should work, but if you truly want to use InStr, you can still do it. Just add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll, and a "using Microsoft.VisualBasic;" at the top of your file, and you can use `Strings.InStr`:
Like `Strings.InStr(searched, sought)`

Answer (score 0):

The three methods are all for different purposes and do not the same. That is why they have different names..

```
int a = String.IndexOf(searched, sought);
```

This is the method that you should use and is exactly for that purpose.
Alternatively you could use `string.Contains()`.

```
int a = String.Compare(searched, sought);
```

Compares two specified String objects, ignoring or honoring their case, and returns an integer that indicates their relative position in the sort order.

```
bool a = String.Equals(searched, sought);
```

Determindes equality of two strings.

Answer (score 0):

Works... Thanks Carsten

```
int b = searched.IndexOf(sought);
```

b = 0

I see the problem I had now... when I move the string to a variable that calculates the string I get the error.  I wasn't sure whether I had the correct use of InStr.